# How to define "framerate" property of videoparse element in gstreamer in C

Tags: c, gstreamer-1.0

I am currently developing an application using gstreamer using C.
I included all the gstreamer library include paths, glib paths, library paths etc. When I try to build an application using Gstreamer lib to play a raw file on the screen, everything works ok.

But, I want to set "framerate" property of the videoparse element described here:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-videoparse.html

But the type of the framerate is GstFraction. But there is no GstFraction data type in the Gstreamer library. Also from the link, I cannot be redirected to the description of GstFraction... (Unlike GstVideoFormat, I found it under the header gst/video/video.h)

I searched many web posts, all of them are about the python API of the gstreamer-sdk.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `fraction` type and so you have to set as follows:

```
g_object_set(videoparser, "framerate", 15, 1, NULL);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
GstElement *videoparser;  
...  
...
g_object_set(videoparser,"framerate","15/1",NULL);
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set